# What does it mean by "Airplanes" does not provide a subscript operator"

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have created a struct variable of type  airplanes but so i have been trying to figure out why i get an error  on the if states ""Airplanes" does not provide a subscript operator" also I am getting another error at part where i call the functions "No matching functions functions 'highest'" Can someone help me

```
count=highest(plane);
count2=lowest(plane);

}


int highest(airplanes plane){
int high=0;
int count=0;
for(int a =0;a<12;a++){
    if(plane[a].averageDeparted>high){
        count=a;
        high=plane.averageDeparted;
    }
}
return count;
  }

 int lowest(airplanes plane){
 int low=100000;
 int count2=0;
 for(int a =0;a<20;a++){
    if (plane[a].averageDeparted< low){
        count2=a;
        low=plane[a].averageDeparted;
    }
   }
 return count2;
```

Comment: `plane[a]` You are trying to apply a subscript operator (pair of square brackets) to a variable of type `airplanes`, but the type `airplanes` apparently doesn't provide a subscript operator. The message seems perfectly clear.

Comment: What type is the variable `plane` at the point where you are calling `highest`? Apparently, it's not in fact `airplanes`.

Comment: it is of type airplanes array userdefined

Comment: `airplanes array userdefined` There is no such type in C++. Show the actual declaration - don't describe it in prose.

Comment: Do you mean "'Airplanes' does *not* provide a subscript operator"?

Comment: plane is of type airplanes

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik it is of  type airplanes
                                          ;inline `airplanes plane[12]`,

Comment: Clearly you *do* mean 'does not provide'. Don't be sloppy about error messages.

Comment: No, it's of type `an array of 12 airplanes`. Which is quite different from just `airplaines`. Your function is declared to accept the latter, but you are passing to it the former - an object of a different type. Hence "no matching functions".

Answer (score 0):

Based on your very belated comment, your parameter declarations are incorrect in both methods. They should be `(airplanes planes[])` in both cases.

The type name is also incorrect, as each instance is clearly only one airplane.